# CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating procedure in sql server, My code is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRegistrationId
( 
  @MaxId INT OUTPUT 
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @MaxId = MAX(UserId)  FROM tblRegistration;
return;
END
```

but it gives error saying

> CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'.

Comment: Why are you creating the stored proc in Master, did you mean to create it in your own DB?

Comment: Some information needs to be added in your question. How do you login in Sql Server? (Windows Authentication/SQL Authentication), Do you have administrator rights? If you are login with SQL Authentication then does your sql login have full rights?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
USE <Your Database Name>
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetRegistrationId(@MaxId INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @MaxId=MAX(UserId)  FROM tblRegistration;
RETURN;
END
```

OR

> Select "**Your Database Name**" from Toolbar (*SQL Editor*) and then Execute the procedure

[image: Select your DB]

Comment: 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Answer (score 5):

Try below of any techniques.

On top of your create procedure statement write this `USE [YOUR_DBNAME]`.

```
USE [YOUR_DBNAME]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRegistrationId
( 
  @MaxId INT OUTPUT 
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @MaxId = MAX(UserId)  FROM tblRegistration;
return;
END
```

**or**

In SQL Server, At your `SQLQuery Editor` choose your target database from available Database drop down list and execute your Stored Procedure.

Comment below if you still face any issue.

Comment: With the third approach of using a fully qualified name, OP will get the same error as he would still be trying to create the SP in master

Comment: 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Answer (score 1):

Switching context to your DB would be the best approach. Hard coding

```
USE <YourDB>
```

in the beginning of the procedure, or using a fully qualified name to include DB name will make the SP less portable